# Using a Perl script how to sum values in one column based on another column in Excel?

Tags: excel, perl

I am new to Perl programming. Let's say we have 2 columns in a sheet `A` of an Excel workbook.

```
AB      Volume
100     280
137     250
150     375
100     100
100     600
137     200
```

Now, I want the output in another sheet. Let's say `B`. I want to sum up `Volume`s based on `AB`.

The output should be like:

```
AB      Volume
100     980
137     450
150     375
```

Please help me in achieving this.

**This is the code I had written for this**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = ReadData ("Book1.xlsx");
my $worksheet = $workbook->[1];

my $max_rows = $worksheet->{'maxrow'};
my $max_cols = $worksheet->{'maxcol'};
my $C1;
my $total = 0;
my $sum;

my $workbook_new = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('New.xlsx');
my $worksheet2 = $workbook_new->add_worksheet();

for my $row_num (1..($max_rows))

{

  if ($row_num>1) 

  {

   my $temp1 = 'A'.$row_num;
   $C1 = $workbook->[1]{$temp1};

   for $row_num (1..($max_rows))

     {
        if ($row_num>1) 

           {
             my $D1 = 'A'.$row_num;

             my $D2 = $workbook->[1]{$D1};


             if ($C1 = $D2) 

              {
                 my $Z2 = 'B'.$row_num; 

                 $sum = $workbook->[1]{$Z2};

                 $total= $sum + $total;

              }
           }
      }

  print "value of C :".$C1 "SUM :".$total."\n"; 

  }

 }
```

I am not getting the output correct as well as not able to figure out how to write the output to the Excel file New.xlsx.

Comment: Just posted it petric..

Answer (score 1):

Start by using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) (to get the results into the Excel file again).

Going line by line, add the values to a hash; Something like this should do the trick:

```
    for (2 .. $worksheet->row_range()) {
      $total{ $worksheet->get_cell($_, 1) } += $worksheet->get_cell($_, 2);
    }
```

This means that in the end your hash `%total` should have the results you're looking for:

```
    {
      100 => 980,
      137 => 450,
      150 => 375
    }
```

You just have to fill in the parsing and the writing of the file.

Comment: I am getting this Error

Can't call method "row_range" on unblessed reference

Comment: That means that whatever you're trying to call `row_range` on isn't an object. If you're doing `$worksheet->row_range()`, try something like `print ref($worksheet)` to see what it is.